# How to find and replace string with spaces for 8,000 plus HTML files

Tags: replace

I want to perform a find and replace in my 8,000 (plus) records (html files) but the problem is the string that i will replace contains spaces.

I want to find all files that has an instance of `</head>` so I could insert my google analytics before the `<head>` tag closes.

**my google Analytics looks like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

after finding `</head>` the result should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>
```

On my server, I have **FTP** & **SSH** access. What approach should I use to replace them fast and lightweight?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sed` over all html files.

`sed 's/<\/head>/before end head/' input.html`

just replace 'before end head' as your need. don't forget to use `\` properly.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [sed append](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... would you mind providing some example how to do it? I'm not familiar with the command.